# How to get date and time from "2013-04-03T20:00:00Z" this format in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have go through different links but did not get date and time separately.Please help me if any one know how to get get date and time from "2013-04-03T20:00:00Z" this format in iOS.

Comment: It's very unclear what you need to do. Do you need two separate strings one representing the date and the other representing the time?

Comment: There's a cool website called http://www.stackoverflow.com this question has been answer thousands (literally) of times on there. Go and find your answer and don't ask a duplicate question.

Comment: Exactly you got me right Desdenova.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to access the date:

```
 NSString *dateStr = @"2013-04-03T20:00:00Z";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSDateComponents* components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:flags fromDate:date];
```

Use components.day to access the day etc..

Comment: What is calendar here ?

Comment: [NSCalendar currentCalendar]